# which Translation strategy in javascript in terms of page load and size

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, translation

I have a JS app which talks to a rest API. There's no server side processing of javascript i.e no template generation at server side.

I have roughly 50 views of some 30 resources. resources have say 5-6 attributes (avg 10%) common among them like "name", "author", "total", "amount".

I use generic compiled templates (underscore) for rendering. something like folowing -

```
<dl>
  <% _.each(schema, function(attr, key){ %>
    <dt><%= attr.title %></dt>
    <dd><%= data[key] %></dd>
  <% }) %>
</dl>
```

i need those titles to be localized.

Following two translation strategies doesn't make much sense to me
1. Use some DOM manipulation plugin post rendering to converting strings to localized strings [Cause i am using JS to render in the first place, why have the extra code to convert strings after rendering]

1. Use different templates for different languages for different resources. [i dont like the idea of having 50 different templates for 15 or so different languages]

I am using languages files (basically JSON files containing localized strings for attribute keys) and i have following trade off to make -

**first choice** 
keep separate language files (objects in json) for separate view/resources

- this has the advantage of fast lookup, i can simply merge the language file with my schema objects.
- but the disadvantage is duplication of common keys such as 'name', 'total'

**second choice** 
have one large file with all the keys
 - this has the advantage of size and avoiding duplication but i need to perform look-ups for the keys

**third choice** have a generic file for common keys and separate for resource specific keys. but this fail-check look-up is again expensive.

** In all this i do need a generic file for some strings like "Are you Sure", "Yes", "NO" 
** With file above i mean different structures, which can come from different files to a package manager and to JS. but essentially different objects once they are processed.

Which choice is better for the case considering resource/view numbers and attributes per resource/view is variable and depends on the logged in user.

or am i doing something horribly wrong.

** also for the note - its a backbone.js app.

Comment: The third choice is fine. I don't think the additional lookup would be a bottleneck. Have you measured it?

Comment: it becomes a bottleneck when i have to fall back to generic strings 5 times for a view which has only 8 attributes. And these numbers are just an example, in some cases i have 80+ attributes and doing lookup 80 times for 5 common attributes is a bit off.

Comment: I went with a gettext-ish system which includes some extra markup in the templates. Then a tool to extract the localizable strings and toss into the main gettext database and another tool to generate trees of per-language pre-localized templates. Then each tree gets mashed into one per-language JST blob and the front end choose which one it wants. Sort of all three of your options at the same time with some scripts to automate it all.

Comment: @muistooshort -- that seems something. I have some heavy size constraints though. can you elaborate more on which tools and process.

Comment: Sorry, the whole thing is custom. I thought all the available tools were crap so I built my own system.